# Google maps is working different on flutter iOS

Tags: flutter, google-maps

Hi everyone I've implemented google maps in my flutter app with some customisation's in it just like zooming in to current location, zoom in and out buttons it is working flawless on the android side but on the iOS side it is not working the same as android. It is flutter it should be the same but its not working like it. I've tried some older versions of the package too [Google Maps Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) but still same result the iOS side doesn't picks the location of the user, doesn't zoom's in and there are no zoom in and out buttons either. It does asks for location though and accesses it perfectly but lacks functionality wise.

I've attached android side [image: Picture] of how is working on android, unfortunately I don't have iOS side picture otherwise I would have attached it. If anyone knows what's happening wrong here please let me know.

Comment: I had a similar issue with drawing polygons and circles inside the polygons. It works on android but not IOS